# How to add username and password for xml format with python

Tags: python, django, xml, string, soap

```
def test(login,password):
    data="""<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <soap-env>
        <soap-env:Body>
        <Auth>
        <Login>login</Login><password>password</password>
        </Auth>
        <Ping>
        </Ping>
        </soap-env:Body>
        </soap-env:Envelope>"""
    return data
```

i can't add login and password when i use '+login+' and i can't do format string like this  " "

Comment: why not use```login = 'loginname' password='passwordvalue' f""" <Login>{login}</Login><password>{password}</password> """```

Comment: @pyzer, because it won't escape special characters *(you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/10824407) answer)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below ('f' string)

```
def test(login,password):
    data=f"""<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <soap-env>
        <soap-env:Body>
        <Auth>
        <Login>{login}</Login><password>{password}</password>
        </Auth>
        <Ping>
        </Ping>
        </soap-env:Body>
        </soap-env:Envelope>"""
    return data

print(test('jack','secret'))
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <soap-env>
        <soap-env:Body>
        <Auth>
        <Login>jack</Login><password>secret</password>
        </Auth>
        <Ping>
        </Ping>
        </soap-env:Body>
        </soap-env:Envelope>
```

Comment: it will fail on this password -> `p><&&w0rd`

Answer (score 0):

If you see that data is XML you **have to** use XML module to build it. Building string which looks like XML is not a good idea as it can easily violate standard. Here is how it can *(should)* be done using built-in [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree):

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def test(login, password):
    envelope_uri = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    ET.register_namespace("soap-env", envelope_uri)
    envelope_node = ET.Element(ET.QName(envelope_uri, "Envelope"))
    body_node = ET.SubElement(envelope_node, ET.QName(envelope_uri, "Body"))
    auth_node = ET.SubElement(body_node, "Auth")
    ET.SubElement(auth_node, "Login").text = login
    ET.SubElement(auth_node, "Password").text = password
    ET.SubElement(body_node, "Ping")

    # ET.indent(envelope_node)  # uncomment this to get indented output (python 3.9+)
    return ET.tostring(
        envelope_node,  # root node
        "utf-8",  # encoding
        xml_declaration=True,  # add xml declaration on top
        short_empty_elements=False  # use start/end pair for empty nodes
    ).decode()

print(test("login",  "p<>&sword"))
```

This code will produce next output:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Body>
    <Auth>
      <Login>login</Login>
      <Password>p&lt;&gt;&amp;sword</Password>
    </Auth>
    <Ping></Ping>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

This is **valid XML** *([proof](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator/cbdc90bd))*.

Function from [balderman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69751872/10824407) with same arguments will produce next output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <soap-env>
        <soap-env:Body>
        <Auth>
        <Login>login</Login><password>p<>&sword</password>
        </Auth>
        <Ping>
        </Ping>
        </soap-env:Body>
        </soap-env:Envelope>
```

This is **invalid XML** *([proof](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator/cb60d5dc))*.